# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass when creating a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having two tables "Journeys" and "stop" 
When i create a new journey i need to create one stop. 
The stop is also referencing stations table.This works fine:

```
@stop = Stop.create(Station.find_by("Station name ").id)
```

But when i try the below, its  giving me a

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass error

```
name = "whatever" 
@stop = Stop.create(Station.find_by(name: name).id)
```

Comment: Do you have a `Station` record with name equals to **whatever**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `find`, `find_by` takes a hash parameter, so you should use it like:

```
Model.find_by(field: "value")
```

It's giving you this error because there's no record on the database with the given name. You could also try `find_by!`, that raises a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception when the record doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

How can we be sure `find_by` name returns a `Station` object?  We can't.
This would be safer

```
if station = Stating.find_by(name: name) # returns nil if no record with name
  @stop = Stop.create(station.id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple there is no name entry "whatever" in stations table.

```
Stop.create(Station.find_by(name: name)&.id)
```

If you want to ignore the error and return nil